# Javascript appendChild and code not working

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am new to Javascript I am having a tonne of problems with the program syntax please what's wrong with the program below? I am trying to create a function that takes an argument of an object in the two arrays. These objects does not exist in the DOM but I want to change color when clicked.

```
let availableLibraries = [
 { id: 1, name: 'express' },
 { id: 2, name: 'async' },
 { id: 3, name: 'request' },
 { id: 4, name: 'browserify' },
 { id: 5, name: 'grunt' },
];

let librariesForInstallation = [
 { id: 6, name: 'socket.io' },
 { id: 7, name: 'mocha' },
];

let selectedLibrary = null;

const selectLibrary = function (library) {
// TODO: implement
let newDiv=document.createElement('div');
let newContent=document.createTextNode(library);
document.newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'selected');
document.getElementById('selected').style.backgroundColor='pink';
document.getElementById('selected').style.borderBottomColor='red';
selectedLibrary = {
id:library.id, name:library.name};
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The formatting of your code is confusing, where does the `selectLibrary` function ends ? And then why do you reassign an object to that variable (which by the way is declared as const so reassignment may throw an error  )

Comment: what is this line `document.newDiv.appendChild(newContent);`? seems wrong since `newDiv` never been attached to document.  you want to append the newDiv to the document, then the newContent to the newDiv. the syntax is `parent.appendChild(child)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you had in mind?

```js
const availableLibraries = [
 { id: 1, name: 'express' },
 { id: 2, name: 'async' },
 { id: 3, name: 'request' },
 { id: 4, name: 'browserify' },
 { id: 5, name: 'grunt' },
], librariesForInstallation = [
 { id: 6, name: 'socket.io' },
 { id: 7, name: 'mocha' },
], cnt=document.getElementById("content");

cnt.innerHTML=availableLibraries.concat(librariesForInstallation)
 .map(l=>`<div id="lib${l.id}" class="lib">id:${l.id}, name:${l.name}</div>`).join("\n");
cnt.onclick=ev=>{
 const tcl=ev.target.classList;
 if(tcl.contains("lib")) tcl.toggle("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected {background-color:pink;border-width:0.3em; border-style:solid; border-bottom-color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```